SO2 vs SO2F2 Dipole Moment
Which molecules has the largest overall dipole moment between $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{SO2F2}$?
$\ce{SO2}$ is bent and therefore polar while $\ce{SO2F2}$ is a tetrahedral but the strong $\ce{S-F}$ bonds in $\ce{SO2F2}$ cause a net dipole because of their bond strength and polarity.
I am wondering which effect would contribute to a overall greater dipole moment?

The bond polarity and length are key, not the bond strength per se.

$\ce{SO2}$ has a dipole moment of $\pu{1.62 Debye}$, (Ref. 1) and bond length of $\pu{1.432 A}$. The sulfuryl fluoride molecule $\ce{SO2F2}$ has a dipole moment of $\pu{1.11 Debye}$ (Ref. 2}. In the latter molecule ($C_{2v}$ symmetry), the S-O bond length is $\pu{1.405 A}$, the S-F bond length is $\pu{1.530 A}$, and the angles are $\angle \mathrm{OSO} = 123^\circ$ and $\angle  \mathrm{FSF} = 97 ^\circ$.
The opposing effects of the fluorine and oxygen lead to a smaller dipole moment than in $\ce{SO2}$, but it's hard to say much more than that.
1: J.W. Le Fevre, I.G. Ross, B.M. Smythe, J. Chem. Soc. (1950) 276-283.
2: D.R. Lide, D.E. Mann, R.M. Fristrom, J. Chem. Phys. 26 (1957) 734–739.
